# como ficaria esse listAll() genérico?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, genéricos, jpql

Tenho a seguinte classe/método

```
public class DAO<T>{
    EntityManager entityManager = (...)
    public List<T> listAll(String jpql){
        return entityManager.createQuery(jpql).getResultList();
    }
}
```

funciona, mas ele não está fazendo o uso dos *generics*, a string passada como parâmetro funciona como uma gambiarra.

Como faço para que toda a Classe passada nos *generics* faça um select com a **JPQL**?

Algo parecido com isso...

```
public class DAO<T>{
    EntityManager entityManager = (...)
    public List<T> listAll(String jpql){
        return (List T)entityManager.createQuery("select t from T t).getResultList();
    }
}
```

É lançado o erro dizendo que `T` não é mapeado, realmente não tem como ele saber o que é o T, mas como ficaria então essa consulta usando os *generics*? Obrigado!

Comment: Você não precisa necessariamente passar o JPQL para o método, sendo que você já consegue saber qual `T` está sendo utilizado através de `getClass().getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName()`. Você pode então criar a query dentro do `listAll` sem passar nenhum parâmetro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receba a classe como parâmetro no método e passe para o select.

```
public List<T> listAll(Class<T> clazz){
    return (List<T>) entityManager.createQuery("select t from " + clazz.getName() + " t").getResultList();

}
```